# Commit delete operation only if another async operation succeeds

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

While working with mongoose, I have the following two async operations

```
const user = await userModel.findOneAndDelete(filter, options);
await anotherAsyncFunctionToDeleteSomething(user); // not a database operation
```

But I need to ensure that both deletions happen or reject together. I've thought about putting `trycatch` on second function and recreate the user document if any error is caught (in the `catch` block). However, this doesn't seem like an efficient (or at least appealing) solution.

Comment: If second operation is totally unrelated then there's nothing much you can do. You can later ensure if both records were if that's extremely necessary. You could use [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) to run both promises simultaneously but it'll throw error if either fails so you can retry it.

Comment: @Dharmaraj second function deletes the user from the AWS cognito. Can I use `Promise.all()`? Just because I'm passing the result of the first operation to the next, I think they should be done sequentially.

Comment: @Dharmaraj is there way to recreate the deleted document with that old _id? I mean I'm going to try-catch the second function and recreate the deleted user document with its own object id. Is it possible?

Comment: Yes, you just need to specify `_id` in the `create()` or `insertOne()` method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If second operation is totally unrelated then there's nothing much you can do. You can later ensure if both records were if that's extremely necessary. You could use Promise.all() to run both promises simultaneously but it'll throw error if either fails so you can retry it.
But as you mentioned, you need result of first operation before running the second then you'll have to run those individually.

Yes, you can catch any errors thrown in the second promise and recreate a document with same ID as shown below:

```
const user = await userModel.findOneAndDelete(filter, options);

try {
  await anotherAsyncFunctionToDeleteSomething(user);
} catch (e) {
  console.log(e)
  await collection.insertOne({ _id: new ObjectId("62....54"), ...otherData });
}
```

Comment: I don't know why but I tried `collection.create(doc)` first and then it didn't work, then I changed it to `collection.create(doc.toObject())`

Comment: @VIVID I am not sure what `doc` is here (is that a string?). But create() takes an object as param.

Comment: The `doc` is the `user` in this case, sorry)

Comment: Try checking the docs/interfaces of that object. There maybe some methods and .toObject() must be returning a JSON only